# How to select all columns from a table and the current date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to run this query using `*` without specifying each column in the table

while running this query with each column i am getting output

```sql
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') as "date and time"
         ,* 
from customer
```

expected result is date with displaying all columns using `*`

Comment: Which database are you using as MySQL is not the same as Oracle database...

Comment: Its oracle or mysql you tagged both, im confused

Comment: Mysql does not have to_char.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it is a table **alias** which will do the job.

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') as "date and time", c.* from customer c; 
                                                                   ^^                ^
                                                                   here ...   and here
```